# SQL Server seeking sequence dates in a table and create periods where possible

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a procedure with single dates (not always in sequence) that I want its result to be transformed into smart periods where possible.
I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Here is a sample of the data [**EDIT**:Mind there is a gap on the 8th and 9th] :

It has the **OnDate**, the **RateCode** which is the **same** on the whole result, the **TypeCode**, the **Charge** and the **Adults**.

I want to create periods from sequencing **OnDate**s that have the same **TypeCode**,**Charge** and **Adults**.

Here is a dummy table along with a script for the data

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTable
(OnDate         datetime        null,
 RateCode       varchar(10)     null,
 TypeCode       varchar(10)     null,
 Charge         numeric(10,2)   null,
 Adults         int             null)
 go

INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',300.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-01 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',200.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-02 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00 , 2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-02 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl' ,150.00, 2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-03 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-03 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',150.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-04 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-04 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',150.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',300.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-05 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',200.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-06 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-06 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',150.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-07 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-07 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',150.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-10 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','jnr',250.00,  2
INSERT someTable
SELECT '2014-05-10 00:00:00.000', 'RATE1','dbl',150.00,  2
```

Here is a sample of the result

```
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         300.00  2
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         200.00  2
2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-03 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-03 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-04 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-04 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         300.00  2
2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         200.00  2
2014-05-06 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-06 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-07 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-07 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
```

I am trying to transform it into something like that:

```
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         300.00  2
2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 2014-05-01 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         200.00  2
2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 2014-05-04 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-02 00:00:00.000 2014-05-04 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         300.00  2
2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 2014-05-05 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         200.00  2
2014-05-06 00:00:00.000 2014-05-07 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-06 00:00:00.000 2014-05-07 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 RATE1   jnr         250.00  2
2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 2014-05-10 00:00:00.000 RATE1   dbl         150.00  2
```

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: This is called the "islands and gaps" problem. There's a whole bunch of articles on how to approach solving this in T-SQL. Please first post the version of SQL. If you have a version with analytical functions (lead,lag,dense_rank) it's a lot easier

Comment: Why is the second column "2014-05-01 00:00:00.000" on the first two rows?  How do the number of rows get reduced?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The 2014-05-01 cannot produce a period as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem where you want I think you just want the next `ondate` value for each `ratecode`/`typecode`/`charge`/`adults` combination.

For this version, the difference of row numbers seems sufficient:

```
select RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, Adults,
       min(ondate), max(ondate)
from (select st.*,
             row_number() over (partition by RateCode, TypeCode order by ondate) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, adults order by ondate) as seqnum_2
      from sometable st
     ) st
group by RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, Adults, (seqnum - seqnum_2)
order by RateCode, TypeCode, min(ondate);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6720158400e8b5572b4a3078b6d9fdf7) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you want to take gaps in the dates into account, then the logic is just slightly different:

```
select RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, Adults, dateadd(day, - seqnum, ondate),
       min(ondate), max(ondate)
from (select st.*,
             row_number() over (partition by RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, Adults order by ondate) as seqnum
      from sometable st
     ) st
group by RateCode, TypeCode, Charge, Adults, dateadd(day, - seqnum, ondate)
order by RateCode, TypeCode, min(ondate);
```

I updated the SQL Fiddle with both solutions.

Comment: Thank you! I have a problem with the last period though

Comment: You see there is no 8th, 9th so the l,ast period is invalid

Comment: Amazing and elegant. Thank you